# Add blur to fancybox instead of black dim

Tags: javascript, css, fancybox, prestashop, blur

We are currently trying to add blur to a fancy box overlay with is using a transparent black png as image for the overlay.

II have not used this CSS3 rules before but i hope someone have the knowledge explaining what is needed.

Please have a look at this link and click on the image and it is now opening in fancy box. We would like to make the background blurred.

http://develop.ekenhalsan.se/shop/halsokontroller/9-haelsokontroll-a.html

Any help totally welcome:)

Answer (score 0):

Yep those are good info - i have seen some of them though, and tried them out i detail. 
What is really the issue is to add the blur to the overlay itself - with is an image in png with transparency.Not like the image here - we want the content (page) behind frosted/ blurred) like on the second image.
 I suppose another div layer behind is needed but we don't know how to achieve this..

[What we want:)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5pja.png)

[What we don´t want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsN34.png)

Enjoy your day all:)

Comment: If your overlay has a transparent png, it could be blurred. My code sample uses css color transparency `rgba(0,0,0,.5)`. Visually, I wonder if it makes any difference whether the container(page content) is blurred or the overlay.

Comment: Thanks for your input Maneesphpaal. Perhaps that is the case, that is easily tasted though , with we have naturally done with a lot of different variations and i am sure we are missing something rather simple out here:) . We where hoping that someone that where familiar with this effekt could add som genious of how to make it function- i don't understand precisely what you mean sorry to say. We are trying to add blur or frosted glas instead of the  black overlay that occurs in the n the link above. Thats it.

Answer (score -2):

This effect is popularly known as frosting glass. css-tricks has a good example.

https://css-tricks.com/frosting-glass-css-filters/

--Edit--

Got down voted for link only answer. So, added some **further explanation**

**Codepen**
https://codepen.io/maneesh/pen/oLxOov

**HTML**

```
<div class="container is-blur">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>Background page content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>

<div class="overlay">
    <div class="fancybox">
      Your fancy box content
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container.is-blur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.content {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.fancybox {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

sorry about Lorem ipsum.

**NOTE**

css *filter* is not yet supported by IE. checkout http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

fyi: -ms-filter won't work on IE.

For further exploration of *filter*, checkout the MDN docs
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter

Comment: This is a link only answer, please add some code example.

Comment: wasn't aware of that. Your concern totally makes sense. Updated my answer

Comment: Alright,  Great info - i will have a look at this and get back. Thanks a bunch

Comment: Yep those are good info - i have seen some of them though, and tried them out i detail. What is really the issue is to add the blur to the overlay itself - with is an image in png with transparency.Not like the image here - we want the content (page) behind frosted/ blurred) like on the second image. I suppose another div layer behind is needed but we don't know how to achieve this.. Added images in a second post above...

Comment: Tested this above now in an own html doc. I can't get only the overlay frosted with means basically the background only and not the content. Any ideas someone is much appreciated.. Thanks